# How to get a list of all available (TTF-) Fonts with XeTeX?

Tags: latex, truetype, miktex, xetex

Very neat that I can use any available TrueType font on my Windows machine with MikTex and **XeTeX**.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\title{Fonttest}   
\begin{document} 
  \section{Section Title} {
    \setromanfont{Palatino Linotype}
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  }
  \section{Section Title} {
    \setromanfont{ProggyCleanTTSZBP}
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  }
\end{document}
```

**Is there a way to automatically generate a font test page for every available font?** So that I do not have to type a test page for every available font by hand?

Actually, I do not even know how to get to the *Long Font Name* required for `\setromanfont` -- short of typing it from the screen. The Windows directory only lists the file names, obviously. Maybe this can be done in TeX itself, but I could manage it with a Python script or such like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a worked out answer, but an idea. All you have to do is iterate over all installed font families, for which an API function exists: [`EnumFontFamiliesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162620.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

```
fc-list  | cut -d\  -f2-99 | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

Comment: On the latest (2.9) MikTeX on my windows 10 the command is `miktex-fc-list`.

Answer (score 2):

A two-step-approach

#### 1. Building list of available fonts

For this one can use `albatross`, a command line tool included in tex distributions like texlive. It is designed to find fonts which include certain glyphs, e.g. if you want to typeset a text in English, you can use something like

```
 albatross -b 3 T h e
```

(replace `T h e` with whatever glyphs your font should be able to typeset)

This will give you a list of font names

#### 2. Producing a test page

You can take the list of font names produced in step 1 and let latex iterate over them

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\testphrase}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {
  Adobe Caslon Pro, 
  Adobe Garamond Pro,
  % many more fonts here
  Zapfino}{
  \section{\x}
  \begingroup
    \setmainfont{\x}
    \testphrase
  \endgroup
}
\end{document}
```

[image]